# React Native: Getstream SDK's ChannelList component re-render programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, sdk, getstream-chat

Is there any way to trigger refetch on Getstream's ChannelList component?

I tried to store the sort and filter in useState and tried to reset them on focus. But it did not re-render inner FlatList of ChannelList component.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.